# Sending file to API with Authorization .Net 5

Tags: c#, .net, azure, api

On my system I need to send a file received from a form to an API that will be saved in Azure.
For this sending I need to pass a Bearer Token, the part of the token I was able to make and receive, testing by Postman I can send and receive the access url of the generated file.
In my .Net project I am not able to send the file and receive its url to write to the database. I need to pass this Token and make the uplad to the API URL.
I'll put the code I wrote so far.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadAzure([FromForm] IFormFile file)
{
    var Token = await _tokenAzure.ReturnToken();
    var _urlApi = "https://mysite.dev/api/file/savepdf";
    var _tokenApi = Token.AccessToken;

    if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
        return Content("file not selected");

    HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
    clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

    // Pass the handler to httpclient(from you are calling api)
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);

    byte[] data;
    using (var br = new BinaryReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
        data = br.ReadBytes((int)file.OpenReadStream().Length);
    ByteArrayContent bytes = new(data);
    MultipartFormDataContent multiContent = new()
    {
        { bytes, "file", file.FileName }
    };

    var result = client.PostAsync(_urlApi, multiContent).Result;



    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe want to add the following line of code.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _tokenApi);
```